# Not connecting to server

Tags: technical-issues, terraria-mobile

My son is having problems playing Terraria on Android. It says it cannot connect to server and says install error but it was playing fine last week. It was running fine on our other tablet and all other games working fine.

Comment: If it's saying there's an install error, did you try reinstalling the app?

Comment: Maybe you ran out of space. You can try clearing up device storage and try installing again.

Answer (score 0):

The 'install error' message would imply that there was an error with installing the game, possibly due to an update which the phone is having trouble installing. You should check and try the following:

- Update the game via Google Play Store
- Uninstall and reinstall the game
- Ensure there is adequate storage space on the device
- Ensure the phone is not disconnected from the Google Play store in any way (which could be preventing the update from installing) and that the device has permission to update games